# How can I mutate many columns in dplyr without repeating mutate many times?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am in the process of writing a very not-DRY dplyr chain in R. I need to call `dplyr::mutate() and dplyr::percent_rank()` function on **a lot** of columns from my dataframe, and it would be helpful for me to not have a line of code for each call. My dataframe columns that I need to compute percentiles for have the following pattern:

```
regions <- c("atr2", "sht2", "mid2", "lng2", "all2", "sht3", "lng3", "all3")
suffixes <- c("Made", "Att", "AttFreq", "Pct")
for(i in regions) {
  for(j in suffixes) {
    print(paste0(i, j))
  }
}
```

In the example above I need `8 * 4 == 32` different percentile columns. All 32 initial columns `atr2Made`, `atr2Att`, etc. are already in my dataframe. To compute the percentiles, I have been doing the following:

```
pctile.lineup.data <- pctile.lineup.data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(season) %>%
    # dplyr::group_by(season, homeConfId) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(atr2MadeRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(atr2Made))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(atrAttRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(atr2Att))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(atr2AttFreqRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(atr2AttFreq))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(atr2PctRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(atr2Pct))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sht2MadeRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(sht2Made))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(shtAttRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(sht2Att))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sht2AttFreqRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(sht2AttFreq))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sht2PctRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(sht2Pct))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(mid2MadeRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(mid2Made))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(midAttRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(mid2Att))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(mid2AttFreqRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(mid2AttFreq))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(mid2PctRankNcaa = round(100 * dplyr::percent_rank(mid2Pct))) %>%
    ... %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

Not only do I need 32 different `mutate()` functions, I need to run this code twice for the 2 different `group_by()`s (see the 2nd one commented out). Is there a better way than 64 lines of code? I have a separate datarame that has 21 regions instead of 8, with the same 4 suffixes, and same 2 group_by()s, therefore it would require 21 * 4 * 2 == 168 lines of code to compute these percentiles. This isn't DRY - please help!

Edit: I am obviously looking into `mutate_at`, however I am not very familiar / good with the `_at` version of mutate. There are other columns in my dataframe besides these 32, and so I don't think `mutate_all` would work.

Comment: This sounds like exactly the reason `mutate_at` was created. If you're applying the same function to each of these columns you can do this in a single line

Comment: yes see my edit - i am reading `mutate_at` docs currently and googling for examples on how to do this.

Comment: why wouldn't apply or lapply (for data frames) solve your problem ? I don't know how to use mutate in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `dplyr::mutate_at` is for. Starting with some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:5],
                 item1 = rnorm(5, mean=2),
                 item2 = rnorm(5, mean=5),
                 item3 = rnorm(5, mean=7))
```

The `*_at` functions accept 2 arguments:

- a `.vars` argument that accepts the selector functions used by `dplyr::select`. In this case we use `one_of` to provide a list of variables, but we could simplify this by using `contains` or `starts_with` if there's a pattern to the variables
- a `.funs` argument where we put the function to be applied to each of these columns.

Note that in order to get these argument to work properly, these arguments have to be wrapped in the `vars` and `funs` functions respectively:

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(.vars = vars(one_of('item1', 'item2')),
              .funs = funs(rounded = round(100 * percent_rank(.)))   

  name    item1    item2    item3 item1_rounded item2_rounded
1    A 3.801373 5.701111 9.871991           100            75
2    B 2.264733 5.730916 8.558700            25           100
3    C 3.432726 5.623918 7.359317            75            50
4    D 2.137491 5.286736 7.996114             0            25
5    E 3.227416 5.269252 6.588257            50             0
```

Since the function in `.funs` is named (`rounded = ...`), the result of that operation is made into new variables with the with that name as a suffix. If it was unnamed, then the selected variables would be modified themselves (that is, `item1` and `item2` would be replaced with the rounded versions)